# Error when convert date in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

when I try convert date from field from database I have error:

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

```
@item.FAK_DataW.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy)
```

When I use now date its work

```
@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: what is the type of `FAK_DataW` property ?

Comment: Very simple.. `@item.FAK_DataW` is not a `DateTime` object. It might be nullable DateTime or something else entirely.

Comment: Model:
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FAK_DataW { get; set; }

Comment: and your are missing the closing " in the @item.FAK_DataW.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 1):

Your field is not `DateTime`, it is `Nullable<DateTime>`. You need to access its `Value` property which is `DateTime` like this:

```
@item.FAK_DataW.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

It is recommended, though, to check if it is `null` first. Something like this:

```
@(item.FAK_DataW.HasValue ? item.FAK_DataW.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "")
```

And if you're using Visual Studio 2015, you can then use the `?.` operator like this:

```
@item.FAK_DataW?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```